# the code is showing correct result but character class is not abstract in java so how we are using its method without creating its object?

Tags: java

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;


public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        String A=sc.next();
        String B=sc.next();
        array1=A.toCharArray();
        array2=B.toCharArray();
        array1[0]=Character.toUpperCase(array1[0]);
        array2[0]=Character.toUpperCase(array2[0]);
        System.out.print(array1);
        System.out.print(" ");
        System.out.print(array2);

    }
}
```

Comment: read about static methods.

Comment: In addition to `static` methods, there are `static` fields. In fact, you're using one already without comment. [`System.in`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#in) - which is a `static PrintStream` defined in the `System` class (which you are also using without creating). And that is allowed because it is a **global**. As is [`Character.toUpperCase(char)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#toUpperCase-char-).